# Why is Jersey client inserting an object into my List when it should be empty?

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb, jersey

I've written a client for a REST service using Jersey. For some reason, when the JSON to be unmarshalled has an empty array, the List object has a single element in it. That object has all members set to null as if it was just constructed with the default constructor.

Order.java:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Order {

    private int id;
    private List<Photo> photos;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }
}
```

Client code that consumes the JSON service:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(environment.url);

Order order = webResource.path("Orders")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .post(Order.class, formData);
```

The logs show that the JSON returned was:

```
{"id":704,"photos":[]}
```

However, the List "photos" is not empty as expected, but contains a single Photo object. All members of this object are null as if it was constructed with a default constructor.

What is creating this object and why?

---

**More details**: A similar problem exists if instead of a List of objects, I attempt to deserialize a List of enums. In this case I also get a List of size 1 this time just containing "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a decent answer and just reverted to using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for all the marshalling and unmarshalling of the JSON. It is actually cleaner now as GSON imposes fewer constraints on my POJOs (no need for annotations, or mutability).

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.path("Orders")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, formData);

Order order = new Gson().fromJson(response.getEntity(String.class), Order.class);
```

This is not the solution I was originally looking for. I just posted it as the next best thing (which turned out to be better!).

Answer (score 1):

Add this annotation to your `Order` class:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

this annotation says to `Jackson` serializer to avoid writing objects with null values.

UPD. maybe this annotation should be added to `Photo` class too.